# Can I claim tax withheld on form 1042-S on form 1040

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099, form-1040

I moved from US to India on 8/2011. I was in India through the end of 2011. In 1/2012 I moved back to US. Fidelity has provided me with a form 1042-S. It looks like the equivalent of form 1099 for non-resident aliens. For tax year 2011, I think I am supposed to file a 1040 resident alien tax return as I was in US for more than 6 months. Form 1042-S is usually used in conjunction with form 1040-NR - income tax return for non-resident alien.

My question: since Fidelity did not provide me with the usual 1099, can I claim the tax withheld on 1042-S while filing my tax return form 1040 for 2011? The dollar amount is not huge, its $54.00.